# Instantiate making multiple clones

Tags: unity-game-engine, clone

I'm making a building system in my game and the basic mechanic works but for some reason whenever I place down the object it adds incrementally more clones with every placement. The first placement creates one clone, the second placement creates two clones, the third, three clones, and so on. I fixed it for one object by moving it out of an empty game object that had all the building prefabs in the hierarchy but it only works for that.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class GroundPlacementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject placeableObjectPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    private KeyCode newObjectHotkey = KeyCode.A;

    public NavMeshObstacle nav;

    private GameObject currentPlaceableObject;

    private float mouseWheelRotation;

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleNewObjectHotkey();
        nav = GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>();
        if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
        {
            MoveCurrentObjectToMouse();
            RotateFromMouseWheel();
            ReleaseIfClicked();
        }
    }

    private void HandleNewObjectHotkey()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(newObjectHotkey))
        {
            if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
            {
                Destroy(currentPlaceableObject);                   
            }
            else
            {
                currentPlaceableObject = Instantiate(placeableObjectPrefab);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoveCurrentObjectToMouse()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            currentPlaceableObject.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
            currentPlaceableObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
            currentPlaceableObject.GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>().enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void RotateFromMouseWheel()
    {
        Debug.Log(Input.mouseScrollDelta);
        mouseWheelRotation += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
        currentPlaceableObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseWheelRotation * 90f);
    }

    private void ReleaseIfClicked()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {                
            currentPlaceableObject.GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>().enabled = true;
            print("disabled");
            currentPlaceableObject = null;
            print("removed prefab");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, [mcve] your code boiled down to TLDR.  Im guessing - as there isnt quite enough detail, that this is is on the object? so each time you place down an item it does it for each of the items already in the scene

Comment: Is this script attached to the object that you are cloning (`placeableObjectPrefab`)?

Comment: You should explain where the problem is. HandleNewObjectHotkey (currentPlaceableObject = Instantiate(placeableObjectPrefab);)? ReleaseIfClicked? Or other methods? Right now I don't see anything wrong in your code. It should Instantiate(placeableObjectPrefab) every time you press A (if currentPlaceableObject  is null, if not it should destroy the current currentPlaceableObject)... Still, maybe the problem is Destroy(currentPlaceableObject), because you only destroy the object but you don't initialize the reference to null

Comment: I concur with everyone else, we don't have enough information to say for sure, but my guess is that this script is on the GameObject that's being instantiated

Comment: @Mikedg The script is on the object that should be cloned and thats probably why. I just added all the scripts to a empty gameobject and now it works fine, thanks.